# Proof required for the following problem...

Tags: geometry

Can you please give an explanation of how can I find that $K$ and $P$ are midpoints of respectively $CR$ and $CS$.

NOTE! that:  $AE$ and $DB$ are bisectors of angles
$A$ and $B$. and $CK$ and $CP$ are respectively perpendicular to bisectors that I've already mentioned.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\Delta BCR$ and $\Delta ASC$ are both isosceles triangles. Given that, and that $BK \perp CR$, what can you say about the lengths of $RK$ versus $KC$ (and similarly for the other triangle)?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

- Triangles $\triangle APC$ and $\triangle APS$ are right, have common side and $|\angle CAP| = |\angle SAP|$.
- Similairly, triangles $\triangle BKC$ and $\triangle BKR$ are also congruent.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$